# Telegraf: how to read messages from JMS Queue (activemq)

Tags: json, jms, activemq-classic, influxdb, telegraf

I would like to use a JMS queue (ActiveMq broker) as input for telegraf (in a TICK stack), but I can't find a plugin to do that. Does anyone knows something about?
In the message there will be a json string, so any advice to use other solution can be usefull.
I was thinking to write in a file this json messages and then use the tail plugin, but I'm non sure that is the best solution, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ is a polyglot broker-- meaning it supports a number of protocols and transports. I am not familiar with the TICK stack, or what language it is written in.

If it is written in Java, just use the activemq-client jar. If not Java, a good start would be to look for MQTT, AMQP, WebSocket or STOMP protocol support.

STOMP is a text-based protocol, so you can get PUTs and GETs going pretty quick if you need to write something from scratch.

Comment: The MQTT (or AMQP) protocol looks like a good idea, Telegraf have an input for that. I usually use ActiveMQ only for jms messages, so I have just to look how to configure my broker for mqtt (or amqp).